# Where is the best location for finding information on /yum?

Tags: package-management, yum

So I'm trying install `php-mcrypt` on one server and `git-core` on another server. It seems like locating packages is where I'm falling short. (just learning server administration)

I'm very ignorant of repositories and how they play into the whole installation bit. I know that I need to add additional repositories, but that all confuses me and I never know if I did it right, or if I need to update after...  I'm just confused.

Can you tell me how to manage my `yum` repositories? what commands to use and where I should find repositories. how I can search all of the repositories for a certain package. Just the basic `yum` repositories 101.

Comment: What linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Deployment Guide, Chapter 5](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-yum.html) is about yum. Reading it will answer your questions about "what commands to use". Before doing that, you may want to take a minute and make sure you understand the concept of [package management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system).

For software that isn't already included in the repository provided by your linux distribution, a popular repository is [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

*Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (or EPEL) is a Fedora Special Interest Group that creates, maintains, and manages a high quality set of additional packages for Enterprise Linux, including, but not limited to, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS and Scientific Linux (SL).*

If you use CentOS, [several repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) are enabled by default. You must choose between using the CentOS Extras repository or using EPEL, since they have overlapping packages.

Answer (score 0):

1. I found this information about [yum and RPM handling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-102-5/?ca=drs-) as well.
2. [Handling software repositories](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-using-repositories.html)