# Where can I find a list of all yum repositories?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

Now that I know more about `yum` from my previous question [Where is the best location for finding information on /yum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20819/where-is-the-best-location-for-finding-information-on-yum)

I need to start playing with some new repositories. Where can I find a list of global repositories and what they do? If you don't know of this complete list, just let me know of the repositories that you do know of and what they are good for.

For centos 6

Comment: Repositories for what distribution?

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

Centos wiki
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

Comment: Don't forget to accept this so that the bot doesn't keep dredging it up...